# Silent Local Notification IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Can we have a silent local notification in IOS app. Which does some data processing in the background with out the user interacting with it.

What I want to do is create a silent local notification which fires every 8 am in morning and after the user receives it I want to do some data processing and recreate a new one which the user can see with the new data I processed after I saw the first silent local notification.

I am trying to avoid using push notification as much as I can.

Comment: When a local notification is fired, you won't get any control of the app. It is just something that is visually shown to the user.

Comment: Adding to above, only remote notifications (push) will allow you to do what you want to do.

Comment: Local and push notifications both work the same way in that sense. they don't do anything unless you open them.

Comment: I am looking for the it too. So it is not possible?

Comment: No it is not possible with local notifications. You have to use remote notification for such cases.

Comment: Try this answer. This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161265/ios-silent-local-push-notifications-objective-c/37162574#37162574

Comment: @RuturajDesai I already solved the issue using remote notification because I wanted my notification to happen even when the app is in background.

Answer (score 3):

You can receive silent notifications in the background on iOS, but you will need a server to actually send the notifications.

To do this you enable the `Remote notifications` background mode in your target's Capabilities tab:

[image: Screenshot of Background Modes settings]

Then you register for push notifications in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeNone categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

Pending the user allowing your app to send push notifications, you will receive the device token:

```
 -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;
```

If something goes wrong, the failure handler will be called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

You send the `deviceToken` to your server and tell it to send a silent push notification to that `deviceToken` at the device's local time of 8AM.

That device will have the following app delegate method called:

```
         - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
      fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
```

and you will be able to do your data processing.

Easy!

Don't forget to call the completion handler when you're done!

Comment: When you say a server. It is a non IOS program which sends notification to a device right like scheduled task or some sort? Or can I do everything with in my IOS app,

Comment: It is a non iOS program, e.g. running as a cron job on EC2 or something similar.

Comment: So you are using remote notification. But I am trying to get away from remote notification and my question is about local notifications.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Local notifications can't be silent.

Comment: I really like this answer because, I was hoping I could do a local notification silently. However, you can't, so with this answer I was able to see exactly how I can get the silent notifications that I need.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RhythmicFistman can you give me the source where it says silent local notification is not possible?

Comment: I don't remember where I read that, but it was a long time ago and notifications changed a lot in iOS 10, you should have a look at the documentation.

Comment: And how do we show a local notification when we've received silent push notifications with only json data payloads while the app is in the background?