# iOS Silent local push notifications objective c?

Tags: ios, push-notification, push

I am searching for way to implement silent local push notifications. I want to send silent notification to user when that user is out of range.

Comment: There is no facility to send a silent local notification.

Comment: When you say silent, what do you mean? Do you want to avoid sound? Please explain this further, this question is too broad.

Comment: @dokun1 I am trying send notification which will work in background like Remote silent notifications. User will not see those notifications in notification center.

Answer (score 6):

Solved.
While creating local notification don't set following values.

```
notification.alertBody = message;
notification.alertAction = @"Show";
notification.category = @"ACTION"; 
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

Just crate local notification like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone* timezone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.timeZone = timezone;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

This will send local notification and will only display IconBadgeNumber as 4. No notification will be shown in notification center when app is in background.

**Updated for iOS10 (UNUserNotificationCenter)**

In AppDelegate

```
@import UserNotifications;

UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (!granted) {
                              NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
                          }
                      }];
```

In ViewController

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
//content.title = @"Don't forget";
//content.body = @"Buy some milk";
//content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
content.badge = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:15 repeats:NO];


NSString *identifier = @"UniqueId";
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                      content:content trigger:trigger];

[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
    }
}];
```

This will send a silent notification after 15 sec with badge count as 4.

Comment: Hi @Ruturaj Desai : thanks its working, but i need similar for iOS 10 using UNUserNotificationCenter. any idea please.

Comment: Hi @Ammaiappan, I just updated my answer for iOS 10 (UNUserNotificationCenter). This might help you. Happy coding.

Comment: Hi @Ruturaj Desai, I tried same, and its works perfect when app is in foreground, But in background it does not work. Any work around for background?

Comment: Will it be called if app is not running?